# Add all values in form and display in disabled input

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a form in which there are various amounts of money that need to be recorded. As there are various elements I have displayed these in the code using the `data-*` attribute in JavaScript, in this case `data-money="100"`.

How can I use JavaScript to add all the amounts that are selected up, and display them in a disabled input? This will later be injected into the Database.

I really have no idea how to approach this and how complex it will need to be, otherwise I would have tried something. Thats why I'm asking.

Does it require JS on the page? In the HTML? Or can I control all from my JQuery file?

Example code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="inscriptionPaid" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Enrolment paid</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="inscriptionPaid" id="inscriptionPaid" data-money="800" value="yes" > Yes 
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="inscriptionPaid" id="inscriptionPaid" data-money="0" value="no" checked> No 
            </label>
            </div>
          </div>
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="paidFor" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Paid for</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select id="paidFor" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Choose Option</option>
                <option data-money="3600">IELTS - $3,600</option>
                <option disabled role="separator">---------------</option>
                <option data-money="3600">General English weekdays - $3,600</option>
                <option data-money="2800">General English Saturdays - $2,800 </option>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**EDIT**
I managed to make this however it is not recognising the amounts of the `data-money` tags, I have tried changing the `$(this)each.(function()` part but I can't get it to pick up the information.

```
$('*[data-money]').change(function(){
var sum = 0;
$(this).each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
});
 $("#totalPaid").val(sum);
});
```

Comment: No need for a disabled input. Just use a DIV and style it the way you want.

Comment: do you want to sum up all the data-money values ?

Comment: What do you mean by "require JS on the page"? You will at least need to include the external javascript files (the jQuery lib & your script) in the page.

Comment: Yes @surendran thats what I what to do, sorry if I explain myself badly

Comment: I updated my answer to only get the sum of the selected elements with data-money, hopefully that helps more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this into your jQuery somewhere:

```
totalPrice = 0;
$("[data-money]:selected, [data-money]:checked").each(function() {
    totalPrice += Number($(this).attr("data-money"));
});
```

The idea is to get all the elements have the data-money attribute. Then all you have to do is loop through them and add the values of their data-money attribute to some variable. I hope this is what you were looking for. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fEmb/) in case you want it)

Comment: I copied your JSFiddle and edited it a bit but it does pretty much what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

do you mean somethink like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/h6F2B/1/) simply done with `jquery`

```
 var sum=0;
    $("option").each(function() {

        if(parseInt($(this).attr("data-money"))&&$(this).attr("selected"))  
        sum=sum+parseInt($(this).attr("data-money") )


    });
    $("#test").val(sum) //this is the disabled input element
```

Comment: This is excellent, but how do I only included them if they are selected? This is including all of them.

Comment: see the edit on answer just changed the if statment with `parseInt($(this).attr("data-money"))&&$(this).attr("selected")`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate trough all data-money and put the output in a label, here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3mLjR/.

```
var sum = 0;
$("[data-money]").each(function(e){
sum +=$(this).data("money");
});
console.log(sum)
$("#output").text(sum);
```

Comment: This is great but its adding all of the `data-money` values even if they aren't selected. Do I need to add some `click` functionality?